# Ejabberd hook for banned account

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-hooks

Our hook on muc_filter_presence does not receive calls when user is banned and forced to leave chat room. Is this expected? If so, is there other hook we could use for "user ban" callbacks?
We are using ejabberd 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

The muc_filter_presence is designed to filter presence stanzas sent to the room. In the case of a kick, it's the room the ones that sends it, so it makes sense this event isn't called.

When kicking (or banning) a room occupant, I see this event is called:

```
ejabberd_hooks:run(
  leave_room,
  <<"localhost">>,
  [<<"localhost">>,
   <<"room1">>,<<"conference.localhost">>,
   {<<"baduser">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"tka1">>}]).
```